# Binary I/O Classes (Summing all the integers in a binary data file)

Tags: java, binary, dataoutputstream, datainputstream

Could someone please help me through this problem? I'm not really good with the binary I/O classes.

> Suppose a binary data file named Exercise 13b_1.dat has been created using writeInt(int) in DataOutputStream.  The file contains an unspecified number of integers.  Write a program to find the sum of integers.

Comment: Programming is mostly playing with binary, and you have all the time in the world. So try something, and ask about details that are unclear to you.

Comment: Hint: what method do you think would be used to read things that were written with a method called "writeInt"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("13b_1.dat");
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
int count = 0;

try {
    while (true) {
        dis.readInt();
        count++;
    }

} catch (EOFException e) {}

System.out.println("There are " + count + " integers.");
```

For efficiency, you can read in a bunch of bytes and divide the number of bytes by four, since one integer is four bytes.

Comment: Of course, using exceptions for control flow isn't terribly good style.  If only there was some way to figure out how many ints are in that file.

Comment: @Dmitri: If writeInt writes a constant number of bytes for every argument, you could divide the file length by that number to get the number of integers in the file.

Comment: @Thomas: I was using gentle sarcasm to guide the author of the question towards the path to a solution :)